# copying from subdirectories to one directory windows bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, xcopy

I'd like to copy all files from subdirectories to one destination, using Windows bat.

Example:
Files to copy:
C:\src\a\1.bmp
C:\src\a\2.bmp
C:\src\a\b\3.bmp

Copied files:
C:\dst\1.bmp
C:\dst\2.bmp
C:\dst\3.bmp

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.bmp .\src | Copy-Item -Destination .\dst
```

Using the [classic way](https://superuser.com/questions/256284/in-windows-a-batch-file-with-a-recursive-for-loop-and-a-file-name-including-bla):

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('dir ".\src\*.bmp" /s /b') do (
    copy %%a "./dst/"
)
```